# How to retrieve os_log messages from detached hard drive?

Tags: macos, logging, oslog

My daemon and application generated log messages using os_log(). Unfortunately the Mac mini running macOS Big Sur is no longer running as it always goes to the bootcamp partition when restarted. Now that hard drive has been removed from the Mini and being shipped to me.

When the computer is running, I usually use the log command to retrieve log messages

`log show --predicate 'senderImagePath contains "com.mycompany"'`

My question, is it possible to get the log messages from this particular hard drive when I plug it to the dock? At the moment I don't know what other volumes are available/readable from that drive. If I can get the log messages, I'd like to learn if my daemon had anything to do with the crash.

Where does macOS Big Sur (or Catalina) keep the os_log database? I didn't find any Apple documentation mentioning this, and I know it is not in /private/var/log/system.log.